# logic of pd.groupby.apply() resulting in different shapes based on applied function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe `df`.
I am performing a groupby, followed by some statistics.

```
import numpy 
m=3    
some_stats=df.groupby('c1')[['v1','v2','v3']].apply(lambda g: np.max(g.iloc[m:-m])-np.min(g.iloc[m:-m]))
```

If I use np.max and np.min results are as expected:

```
   v1  v2  v3
c1
8.0        8  10   8
14.0      11  10  11
20.0      10   7   9
30.0      14   9   8
40.0      12   9  10
48.0      23  56  12
56.0      12  14   8
```

However, if I just apply a different numpy summary funciton as `np.percentile`

```
 some_stats2=df.groupby('c1')[['v1','v2','v3']].apply(lambda g:np.percentile(g.iloc[m:-m],90)-np.percentile(g.iloc[m:-m],10))
```

I then get a dataframe which is completely different from the previous in shape.

Why is this logical, and what is the logic behind it?

```
c1
8.0     228.0
14.0    244.0
20.0    345.0
30.0    311.0
40.0    282.0
48.0    333.0
56.0    228.0
dtype: float64
```

Ideally, I would like to get the same result, and understand why regardless if I use np.max or np.percentile(,100)

```
 pd.__version__
Out[86]: u'0.20.2'
```

Comment: It'll be helpful if you provide some sample data